# Need an API / C# Code to read Office 365 Usage Analytics

Tags: office-365, office-365-developer, analytics

I am trying to get hit count of each item (i.e., How many peopled viewed each page).

I am receiving the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll Additional information: The property or field 'TotalHits' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

I'm using this code:

```
 using (var context = new ClientContext(targetWebUrl))
        {
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, pwd);
            Site site = context.Site;

            List pagesList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");

            CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
            ListItemCollection items = pagesList.GetItems(query);

            context.Load(items, li => li);
            context.Load(site);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Analytics.UsageAnalytics UsageAnalyticsObj = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Analytics.UsageAnalytics(context, site);

            List<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Analytics.AnalyticsItemData> lstAnalyticsData = new List<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Analytics.AnalyticsItemData>();

            foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
            {
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Analytics.AnalyticsItemData eachListItemAnalyticsData = UsageAnalyticsObj.GetAnalyticsItemData(1, listItem);
                 context.Load(eachListItemAnalyticsData);
                 context.ExecuteQuery();
                //Getting Error in below line
                Console.WriteLine(eachListItemAnalyticsData.TotalHits);
                lstAnalyticsData.Add(eachListItemAnalyticsData);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Please correct where I am going wrong. Let me know if there are any pointers of MSDN or some useful links.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Going to take a stab in the dark here, and say you need to do a `context.Load(eachListItemAnalyticsData);`

Comment: I tried this option. But I got below error:                                                   An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

Additional information: The property or field 'TotalHits' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Comment: Please add your comments as edits to your question. You can edit your question by clicking the **edit** link under your question.